# BlurEffect applied from ViewModel not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I made an effect called MosaicEffect myself (borrowing code from various places), but in certain situations the mosaic effect does not work, and I am verifying this problem. In order to isolate this problem, I tried it with the existing System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurEffect instead of my MosaicEffect, but it didn't work either, so I think there's something wrong with my method.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ty1S.png

Minimal source code is here:

https://github.com/dhq-boiler/ForStackOverflow/tree/develop/Question20230124/ShaderEffectSample/ShaderEffectSample

Place the Image object dynamically from the ViewModel (MainWindowViewModel.cs),
I want to apply BlurEffect again, but it doesn't work.

Specifically, it is displayed in its original state without blurring.

(In terms of UI, when the button with Grid.Column=1, Grid.Row=3 is pressed)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c94jq.jpg

What is missing?...

Part of ViewModels/MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public ReactiveCommand BlurEffectImage { get; }
        :

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            BlurEffectImage = new ReactiveCommand().WithSubscribe(() =>
            {
                var mosaic = new MosaicViewModel();
                mosaic.Bitmap = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri("../net7.0-windows10.0.22000.0/Assets/Fm2MhTmakAAlBhz.jpg", System.UriKind.Relative));
                var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
                using (var context = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
                {
                    var mainwindow = App.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;

                    //When I add an Image object from ViewModel, the blur effect doesn't work for some reason
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.Source = mosaic.Bitmap;
                    image.DataContext = mosaic;
                    image.Width = mosaic.Bitmap.Width;
                    image.Height = mosaic.Bitmap.Height;
                    RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(image, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
                    mainwindow.test.Content = image;
                    image.Effect = new BlurEffect()
                    {
                        Radius = 30,
                        KernelType = KernelType.Gaussian,
                    };
                    image.UpdateLayout();

                    BitmapCacheBrush _brush = new BitmapCacheBrush(image);

                    //When adding an Image object from ViewModel, the code prepared for testing does not apply the blur effect for some reason
                    //var label = new Label();
                    //label.Content = "TEST";
                    //label.FontSize = 12;
                    //label.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    //label.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                    //var _vbrush = new VisualBrush(label);
                    //_vbrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 0.25, 0.25);
                    //_vbrush.TileMode = TileMode.FlipXY;
                    //var rectangle = new Rectangle();
                    //rectangle.Fill = _vbrush;
                    //rectangle.Width = 1000;
                    //rectangle.Height = 1000;
                    //var effect = new BlurEffect();
                    //effect.Radius = 30;
                    //effect.KernelType = KernelType.Gaussian;
                    //rectangle.Effect = effect;
                    //mainwindow.test.Content = rectangle;
                    //rectangle.UpdateLayout();
                    //BitmapCacheBrush _brush = new BitmapCacheBrush(rectangle);

                    context.DrawRectangle(_brush, null, new Rect(0, 0, mosaic.Bitmap.Width, mosaic.Bitmap.Height));
                }
                OpenCvSharpHelper.ImShow("BlurEffectResult", drawingVisual, (int)mosaic.Bitmap.Width, (int)mosaic.Bitmap.Height);
            });
            :
        }
    }
```

Helpers/OpenCvSharpHelper.cs:

```
    static class OpenCvSharpHelper
    {
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        public static void ImShow(string windowTitle, BitmapSource rtb)
        {
            FormatConvertedBitmap newFormatedBitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
            newFormatedBitmapSource.BeginInit();
            newFormatedBitmapSource.Source = rtb;
            newFormatedBitmapSource.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
            newFormatedBitmapSource.EndInit();

            var mat = OpenCvSharp.WpfExtensions.BitmapSourceConverter.ToMat(newFormatedBitmapSource);
            OpenCvSharp.Cv2.ImShow(windowTitle, mat);
        }

        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        public static void ImShow(string windowTitle, System.Windows.Media.Visual visual, int width, int height)
        {
            var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            rtb.Render(visual);
            ImShow(windowTitle, rtb);
        }

        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        public static void ImShow(string windowTitle, VisualBrush brush, int width, int height)
        {
            var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
            {
                context.DrawRectangle(brush, null, new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, width, height));
            }
            rtb.Render(visual);
            ImShow(windowTitle, rtb);
        }
    }
```

What I have tried:

As you can see in the image and code, the **XAML definition and placing the Image object from the code-behind (MainWindow.cs) worked well.**

Below code is working:

Part of Views/MainWindow.xaml:

```
        <Image
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Source="../Assets/Fm2MhTmakAAlBhz.jpg">
            <Image.Effect>
                <BlurEffect Radius="30" />
            </Image.Effect>
        </Image>
        <Image
            x:Name="baseImage"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Source="../Assets/Fm2MhTmakAAlBhz.jpg">
            <Image.DataContext>
                <viewModels:MosaicViewModel>
                    <viewModels:MosaicViewModel.Bitmap>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="../Assets/Fm2MhTmakAAlBhz.jpg" />
                    </viewModels:MosaicViewModel.Bitmap>
                </viewModels:MosaicViewModel>
            </Image.DataContext>
            <Image.Effect>
                <effects:MosaicEffect
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=baseImage, Path=ActualWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=baseImage, Path=ActualHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Bytecode="{Binding Path=Bytecode.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Cp="10"
                    Rp="10" />
            </Image.Effect>
        </Image>
        <ContentControl
            x:Name="manualBlurEffect"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1" />
        <ContentControl
            x:Name="manualMosaicEffect"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2" />
```

Part of Views/MainWindow.cs:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            {
                //Display Blurred image by Code behind
                var imageBlurEffect = new Image();
                imageBlurEffect.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Assets/Fm2MhTmakAAlBhz.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                this.manualBlurEffect.Content = imageBlurEffect;
                var blurEffect = new BlurEffect();
                blurEffect.Radius = 30;
                imageBlurEffect.Effect = blurEffect;
            }
            :
        }
    }
```

I would expect to see a properly blurred image when I press the button.

It is clear that:

- The Image object must be in a panel somewhere in the View (probably the parent element is required).
- You have to do image.UpdateLayout() after putting it in the panel.

I apologize for the long question.

Comment: Normally you wouldn't create the image and add it to the view from a view model class. Doing it from code-behind should be the way to go.

Comment: Your working example doesn't use the OpenCvSharpHelper. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: You should template out your viewmodel into UI. You can then have xaml you know works and bind the url for your image or an image source. Which would then be mvvm friendly.

Comment: Whats that ImShow line intended for?  It's converting bitmapsource to Mat?  BitmapSourceConverter.ToMat ?

Comment: After the OpenCvSharpHelper.ImShow method converts the parameter DrawingVisual instance to an OpenCvSharp.Mat instance, the image is displayed with the OpenCvSharp.Cv2.ImShow method. It wraps OpenCv's cv::imshow function. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563

Comment: I have the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/c94jq.jpg the image is rendered even though it is not blurred so I believe there is nothing wrong with the OpenCvSharpHelper.ImShow method .